# What is the best practice for returning type when the function is making object based on string?

Tags: typescript, function, object, types

I have the follow function that is retuning an object when a string is provided. I defined as any but I wonder if exists a better type or generic type even when the object structure is unknow

This is the function:

```
const decodeParameters = (params: string): any => {
  return decodeURI(params)
    .split('&')
    .reduce((result, current) => {
      const [key, value] = current.split('=');

      result[key] = value;

      return result;
    }, {});
}

// https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-drs5f6?file=index.ts
const queryParametersObj1 = decodeParameters('file=index.ts');
console.log(queryParametersObj1)
```

Output:

```
{file: "index.ts"}
```

[Live sample.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-drs5f6?file=index.ts)

Comment: [Please include all relevant code as plaintext in the question itself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/2887218). Links to code are not sufficient to be a [mre]. Until the code is included here as plaintext, the question risks being closed as needing debugging details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your return type is `Record<string, string | undefined>` since you may have an object that can have any key, but the values are always string or undefiend.

```js
const decodeParameters = (params: string): Record<string, string| undefined> => {
  return decodeURI(params)
    .split('&')
    .reduce((result, current) => {
      const [key, value] = current.split('=');

      result[key] = value;

      return result;
    }, {});
};

const queryParametersObj2 = decodeParameters(
  'q=return+unknow+object+in+method+typescript+what+type&rlz=1C1GCER_en&oq=return+unknow+object+in+method+typescript+what+type&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOdIBCTEyNjAwajBqN6gCALACAA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8'
);

//here we have type safety on the value since it is a string
if (queryParametersObj2['q'] !== undefined) {
  console.log(queryParametersObj2['q'].split('+'));
}
```

[Here is a working fork on your example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-h7puof?file=index.ts)

Comment: Could you please include the answer code here as plaintext?  Links to code are at most supplementary.